# Edit form in Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I am not using Doctrine's generator because I think the code is ugly, thus I am trying to make it work my `editAction` and render the form in my `edit.html.twig` page, but I can not make it work. I tried to follow other examples given by other answers but they did not work either.

First, my `editAction`.

```
public function editAction($id, Request $request)
{
    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity = $manager->getRepository('PanelBundle:Material')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('O material procurado não está cadastrado');
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(new MaterialType());
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->submit($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $manager->merge($entity);
            $manager->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Material alterado');

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('panel_materials'));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('PanelBundle:Material:edit.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity
    ));
}
```

Now, my Twig

```
{% extends '::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Editar {{ entity.name }}{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Editar {{ entity.name }}</h1>

        <form action="{{ path('panel_edit_material', { 'id': entity.id }) }}" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form_row(entity.name) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form_row(entity.description) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form_row(entity.quantity) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form_row(entity.price) }}
            </div>

            {{ form_rest(form) }}

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Alterar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Two things: if I remove the `{ 'id': entity.id }`, an error is shown saying a mandatory field is missing, if I let it like it is now, it says `searchAndRenderBlock() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Form\FormView`, and if instead of returning `$entity` in controller, and return `$form->createView()`, the error says `FormView could not be converted to string`

Answer (score 0):

The `FormView could not be converted to string` error is probably caused when attempting to pass the entity id to the path function at `{ 'id': entity.id }`.

The easiest solution to me seems to be to pass the form to the view (as you said you tried), but to remove the whole `action="{{ path('panel_edit_material', { 'id': entity.id }) }}"` attribute from the `form` tag.

If the `action` attribute is missing, it will default to the current url (which should work if I understand the example).

If this does not work, you can still pass the id of the entity in this way: `{{ path('panel_edit_material', { 'id': form.id.vars.value }) }}`. This also requires you to pass the form to the view instead of the Entity.

Hope this helps :)

**Edit**: upon re-reading, I noticed the use of `{{ entity.name}}`. If you pass the for to the view, this will need to be changed to `{{ form.name.vars.value }}`, or you simply need to pass both the `entity` and the `form` to the view, so you can choose to display either the original value or the new value

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve it thanks to the Brecht's enlightenment.

The solution in my case was to remove the `form_row(..)` from the page and leave only like this:

```
<form action="{{ path('panel_edit_material', { 'id': entity.id }) }}" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_rest(form) }}
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Alterar</button>
</form>
```

In the Controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new MaterialType(), $entity);
```

and:

```
return $this->render('PanelBundle:Material:edit.html.twig', array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),
    'entity' => $entity
));
```

And that's it.